# Why jobs not scheduled in this nunit tests

Tags: asp.net-core, hangfire

The first time it passed, however the second time the `recurringJobDtos.Any()` is always false.

```
<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
<PackageReference Include="Hangfire.Core" Version="1.7.34" />
<PackageReference Include="hangfire.aspnetcore" Version="1.7.34" />
<PackageReference Include="Hangfire.InMemory" Version="0.*" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.5.0" />
<PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.3" />
```

```
using Hangfire;
using Hangfire.Server;
using Hangfire.Storage;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace ClassLibrary1 {
    public class MyClass {

        [TestCase(1)]
        [TestCase(2)]
        [Test]
        [Order(0)]
        public async Task Test(int not_used) {
            
            var defaultBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder();
            var webHost = defaultBuilder
                .ConfigureServices(services => {
                    services.AddHangfire(configuration => { configuration
                            .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
                            .UseDefaultTypeSerializer()
                            .UseInMemoryStorage();
                        })
                        .AddHangfireServer();
                })
                .Build();
            webHost.Start();       

            var jobId = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name;
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(jobId,
                () => new TestJobDI().TestJobId(null),Cron.Never);

            RecurringJob.Trigger(jobId);

            var b = false;
            do {
                var recurringJobDtos = JobStorage.Current.GetConnection().GetRecurringJobs();
                if (recurringJobDtos.Any()) {
                    b = recurringJobDtos.First().LastJobState.StartsWith("Suc");
                }
                
            } while (!b);

            await webHost.StopAsync();
            webHost.Dispose();
            
        }
    }


    public class TestJobDI {

        public void TestJobId(PerformContext context) {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is not to use the static method `AddOrUpdate`. Instead I used the `IServiceProvider` and the `IRecurringJobManager`

```
serviceProvider.GetService<IRecurringJobManager>()
                .AddOrUpdate(jobId,
                () => new TestJobDI().TestJobId(null),Cron.Never)
```